# issue with changing codes with ssh and SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I changed some codes on the server via ssh. But later on, my fellow worker told me that I should do it through svn, so I checked out the trunk using TortoiseSVN, but in the source codes that I checked out, I did not see my custom codes. So my question is:

1. why my custom codes that I did via ssh is not in the source codes that I checked out?
2. What should I do now? Should I put my custom codes into the checked out source codes and commit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Because you didn't check in (commit) your changes via SVN, they're not in the repository to check out. You need to do everything through the repository using SVN (or the appropriate client like `TortoiseSVN` on Windows). It's usually a bad idea to ever make changes directly on the server.

2) You should update the code you checked out with your changes, and then check in those changes to update the repository properly (again using SVN or the appropriate client).

If you're not sure how to properly work with SVN and repositories, you should ask your fellow worker for specific instructions, before you do something that causes problems that may get you in trouble (or cost you your job).